# Sde with linear growth

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

- Let $a,b : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel functions with linear growth.
- Let  $X$ be the solution of

$$ X_t= \int_{0}^t a(s,X_s) dW_s + \int_{0}^t b(s,X_s) ds , t \in[0,T]$$

- $\tau_n := \inf \{ t \geq 0, |X_t| \geq n\}$

1. Show that $E( \sup_{t \leq T} |{X_t}^{\tau_n} |^2 ) < \infty$
2. With Gronwall lemma, show the existence of $C$ a constant independant of $n$ such that
   $E( \sup_{t \leq T} |{X_t}^{\tau_n} |^2 ) < C$
3. $E( \sup_{t \leq T} |{X_t}|^2 ) < C$

---

1. We may use somewhat the  [Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280256/application-of-the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality?noredirect=1&lq=1)

\begin{align*}
Z_t & ={X_t}^{\tau_n} \\
\mathbb{E} \sup_{t \leq T} |Z_t|^2 &\leq C_1 \mathbb{E}\langle M \rangle_T^{2/2} \\
&= C_1 \int_{0}^T a(s, M_s)^2 ds \\
&\leq C_1 \sup_{t \leq T} (1 + |Z_T|)\\
&\leq C_1 (1+n) \\
&< \infty \\
\end{align*}

2. We use the [following inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196887/abc2-leq-4a24b24c2)

\begin{align*}
Z_t & ={X_t}^{\tau_n} \\
Z_t^2 &\leq 2 x_0^2 +  2| \int_{0}^t a(s,Z_s) dW_s |^2 + 2 | \int_{0}^t b(s,Z_s) ds | ^2 \\
\end{align*}

We evaluate each term separately.
\begin{align*}
E ( \sup_{t <T} | \int_{0}^t a(s,Z_s) dW_s |^2 ) &\leq C E( | \int_{0}^t |a(s,Z_s)|^2 ds   | ) \\
&\leq C E (  \int_{0}^T  (1+ |Z_s| )^2  ds) \\
&\leq C' E (  \int_{0}^T ( 1+  \sup_{t <T} |Z_s|^2 ) ds )
\end{align*}

We use the Jensen inequality with expectation with respect to an uniform distribution.

\begin{align*} 
\left| \int_0^t b(s,X_s) \, ds \right|^2 &= t^2 \left| \int_0^t b(s,X_s) \, \frac{ds}{t} \right|^2\\
 &\leq t^{2-1} \int_0^t |b(s,X_s)|^2 \, ds \\ 
&\leq K^2 T^{2-1} \int_0^t (1+|X_s|^2) \,ds \\ 
&\leq K^2 T^{2-1} \int_0^t \left( 1+ \sup_{r \leq s} |X_r|^2 \right) \, ds\end{align*}

- $u(t) := \mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{r \leq t} |Z_r|^2 \right)$
- $ u(t) \leq c_1 + c_2 \int_0^t u(s)ds$
- $u(t) \leq c_1 e^{c_2 t} \leq c_1 e^{ c_2 T}$ by Gronwall inequality

3. Fatou Lemma

$E( \sup_{t \leq T} |{X_t}|^2 ) = E ( \liminf \sup_{t \leq T} |{X_t}^{\tau_n}|^2 )  \leq  \liminf E ( \sup_{t \leq T} |{X_t}^{\tau_n}|^2 ) < \infty  $

Comment: In (3), why is $E(\sup_{t \leq T} |X_t|^2) ] = E(\sup_{t \leq T} |X_t^{\tau_n}|^2)$?

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected.

Comment: Looks good! So I guess you've solved your own question?